# How to clear a string after Textbox is set?

Tags: java, android

I have an app with multiple TextBoxes where in order to identify which TextBox to write to (my microcontroller is sending the data to be written), I append a string as a prefix to whatever should be set in my TextBox. Based on the string received, I set the TextBoxes as follows -

```
BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {    
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String text = intent.getStringExtra("");
        messages.append(text);
        if(messages.toString().length()>5 && messages.toString().substring(0,6).equals("bb1010"))
        {
            FirmwareVersion.setText(messages.substring(6));                
        }
       else if(messages.toString().length()>5 && messages.toString().substring(0,6).equals("bb1020"))
        {
            DeviceId.setText(messages.substring(6));
        }
    }
```

The problem is, suppose I prefix a string `"bb1010"`, `FirmwareVersion` TextBox is set appropriately. Now, I send `"bb1020"`, it gets concatenated with what ever is stored in `messages`. So, `messages` looks something like - "bb1010Firmware Version is v1.0.0 bb1020".So,it enters my first if statement and `FirmwareVersion` TextBox is set again. 
So my question is - how do I clear my `messages` after my `FirmwareVersion`TextBox is completely set?

Also, is there any other way in which I can identify which TextBox to write to?

Comment: FirmwareVersion.setText("");

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
messages.setText("");
```

Answer (score 0):

On the Start of your onReceive method declare the String as empty or null as ::--

messages = null;

Or

messages = "";

Both would empty your String and would clear its all content at start so that it wont messes with your operations..

Appreciate the effort if it helps you....

Comment: setting the messages to null will result in an object reference error when using messages.substring(6). Emptying the messages to blank string ("") or string.Empty should suffice in this regard.

Comment: You can use the if conditions to see if messages is empty or not and then move ahead . Only to be sure that it doesnt arise any problem.